# Error reinstalling a chroot?

Tags: chromebook, chroot

I've been running Ubuntu (Unity) on a chromebook for a couple of years. I had to reformat the device and now I'm trying to reinstall from a backup. I've downloaded [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) and copied my backup called `trusty_backup.tar.gz` to the downloads directory. Whenever I run the reinstall script to install the chroot from the backup I get the error `trusty_backup.tar.gz not found`.

This is the command I am using: `sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -f trusty_backup.tar.gz`

What have I got wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately the Crouton installation and boot processes aren't officially supported and therefore off topic here. You can ask questions about any Linux distribution over on [Unix.SE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo sh -e ./crouton -f trusty_backup.tar.gz
```

Comment: I get sudo: edit-chroot: command not found

Comment: What is your desktop enviornment? xfce,unity?

Comment: I was running Unity.

Comment: Answer edited :)

Comment: For some reason I get sh: Can't open crouton

Comment: Answer edited again :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60171/discussion-between-arun-and-julianj).